# How to stop Delphi 11 "Close All" closing the IDE welcome screen

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

This an annoyance in the latest Delphi 11 Alexandria release with all updates installed.

Different behaviour to all previous versions....

Hitting "File/Close all" to clear the project from the IDE removes the welcome page.

Have to select View/Welcome page to get it back again.

Anybody know of any settings to stop this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you uncheck the *"Close Welcome screen when opening a project"* option then the welcome screen tab remains open while you work on your project.  Selecting *"Close All..."* afterwards closes the project but leaves the welcome screen up.

[image: Saving and Desktop Options Dialog]

Comment: Thank you, been searching for a setting, should have scrolled down on that page.